# Connecting output as input in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, spatial-join, dissolve

I want to use the output of the the merge function to be the input for the dissolve function and further on for the spatial join function. However, it is only possible to use as a precondition. I want this tool to be a generic tool that people can use with their own input layers. In my model i did not add any data yet, because people have to specify the inputlayers themselves.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tool Validation is preventing this. Because the output of merge is not set, the schema of the "polygons merged" dataset is unknown. As Merge could output either a table or feature class, dissolve and spatial join is saying "nope, not going to let you hook something with an unknown schema until I know what it is".

You can provide some input to merge, this will set the expected output schema. After that, you'll be allowed to connect your merge output to dissolve and spatial join. You can then go back, and clear out the merge input. This should leave the tool in a connected, ready to go state.